# Why are the Fourier's coefficient on $0,2\pi$ and $-\pi,\pi$ the same?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I was given the Following Fourier's coefficient and I was happy with it:

$$\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
a_n(f)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \cos\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
b_n(f) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \sin\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
    \end{array}
\right.$$

but I had an exercise:

> Let be the function $f$ with a period of $2\pi$ defined for all $x\in[-\infty,\infty[$ by $f(x)=x$. Find the Fourier's coefficient associated to $f$.

and the formulas used in the correction were:

> $$\left\{
>     \begin{array}{ll}
> a_n(f)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} f(x) \cos\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
> b_n(f) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} f(x) \sin\left(nx\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
>     \end{array}
> \right.$$

I **feel** that its the same formulas. But I can't see it...

**Can you help me see why are they alike?**

---

Okay, from Wikipedia it is:

$$\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
a_n(f)=\frac{2}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(t) \cos\left(nt\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
b_n(f) = \frac{2}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(t) \sin\left(nt\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
    \end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: For your original $a_n$ and $b_n$, the normalization constants in front of these integrals should be the same. I'm assuming that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions are periodic, so the integral over an interval of period length does not depend on the choice of endpoints:

$$\int_a^{a+2\pi} f(t)dt = \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)dt $$

for any real $a$, in case the period is $2\pi$. To prove this look at the coordinate transformation $t\mapsto t+a$ and make use of $f(t)=f(t+2\pi).$